# Using OAuth to limit access to corporate webservices for mobile webpages and native apps

Tags: javascript, authentication, ios5, oauth

I am considering a design that I am not certain if OAuth is going to be a good fit, but this is the basic issue.

I have corporate webservices that will require different levels of security.

1. Check grades for user - require username/password
2. Change grades for user - require username/password/RSA token number

So, if an application wants to do (1), it will be asking for the credentials, but, I would like the OAuth server to be told which service the user is trying to get to, and the correct fields would be shown, as this is the initial login.

Now, the second time, the application (browser or app) have a token, but, that token isn't sufficient, but, the application shouldn't know this, as the security requirements may change, based on what the security people decide is appropriate.

So, when the token is presented to get to (2), it determines that it isn't sufficient, and so an error is returned back, so the application can go and try to get a new token.

I haven't implemented any of this yet, but as a basic design I am not certain if OAuth is a good fit for what I want to do, or if I would be better off to write my own authentication system.

Initially the client for the webservices will be mobile web apps, but, I want to make it flexible enough so that when we write a native phone app it will be able to use the same system.  So, having the application needing to know the security I have problems with, and passing the credentials each time to the webservice I am not happy with, so I would prefer to have an encrypted token that can be used, and if you meet the requirements for (2) then you can get into (1) with the same token.

So, would OAuth be a good fit for this?

OAuth does have authentication aspects, it appears, based on this (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp).

**UPDATE:** - It appears that Open Connect (http://openid.net/connect/) may be better than OAuth for this, but I am just learning about Open Connect now.

Comment: Remember that OAuth by itself deals with authorization and isn't concerned with authentication.

Comment: @Kos - I guess my difficulty is that I want to have the authentication part in case the authorization part doesn't meet the requirements. So, you don't have authorization for (2), but you did for (1), so you need to be redirected first to get authenticated for (2).  I am leaning toward just building my own system, but would like to leverage accepted standards (or drafts) as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are two benefits of using oAuth in my opinion...

1. Users don't need to create a new username/password for your service.
2. You don't need to store a password or have a ssl cert for logging in (maybe you need ssl for other things, not sure).

You mention you have two services. You don't want users to have to log in into both so I suggest to create a facade (webservice) where a user logs into (using oAuth), because you need to configure a single callback url. From that facade service you can authorize certain calls and forward these calls to the others services.

I'm not sure what user [Kos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399317/kos) means, but oAuth is for authentication and not for authorization in your app (is my believe). You need to map an oAuth user with an internal representation of that user together with access rights. This still means you need to store a user somewhere on your side. The only thing is that you don't need to store a password and you don't need to develop a custom login page.

So in short oAuth can only tell you that a certain user is known and is authenticated. The rest is up to you. Implementing oAuth is not that hard, but isn't trivial either. So this brings us back to the two benefits I mentioned earlier and you have to decide if and why you want to take this route.